# Error when running PythonWin

Tags: python, python-2.7, traceback

I want to write scripts for ArcGIS (ver 10.4.1). For the purpose I was planning to use PythonWin. But after installation, when I'm running the program the Python Traceback pops up :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 181, in InitInstance
    import interact
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\interact.py", line 31, in <module>
    import winout
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\winout.py", line 233, in <module>
    import pywin.scintilla.view
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\view.py", line 722, in <module>
    LoadConfiguration()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\view.py", line 708, in LoadConfiguration
    configManager = ConfigManager(configName)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\config.py", line 123, in __init__
    line, lineno = self._load_keys(subsection, fp, lineno)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\config.py", line 270, in _load_keys
    sc, flag = keycodes.parse_key_name(key)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\scintilla\keycodes.py", line 91, in parse_key_name
    return vk, flags | this_flags
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

How can I fix this problem?